# Requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin

Tags: kotlin

How to find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update \android\build.gradle:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip`

```
buildscript {
   // ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'   
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.23'   

    repositories {
```

I don't know why this is hapening, how can I fix that?

Comment: So, what is the problem? What is happening, what do you want to fix?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.